# Getting 404 page on page refresh using node and angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-ui-router, http-status-code-404

I am new in `Angular`. I tried to create a CRUD operation using `Nodejs` and `Angular`. I am using `Nodejs` and `Express` for backed and `Angular` for frontend.

When I navigate on page using routerLink its work fine, but when I navigate on the page and then I refresh the page it shows a page not found error.

I know what happened there, the route is not defined in the Express app so I refresh the page it shows the 404 error.

How do I make this work with Angular and Express routes?

Here is my code.

`app.js` ( Server )

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const http = require('http');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MEAN-blog')));


app.get('/',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MEAN-blog/index.html'));
});

app.post('/register',(req,res) =>{
    var u = new User(req.body);
    u.save();
    res.send(u).status(200);
})


var server  = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(8080,'0.0.0.0',() =>{
    console.log('Server is running on 8080');
})
```

Here is the routes of angular

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path : '',
        component : PostsComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'users',
        component : UsersComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'users/:id',
        component : UsersComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'post/:id',
        component : PostDetailsComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'login',
        component : LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path : 'signup',
        component : SignupComponent
    },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am using angular 5

how can i solve this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: what is the default router path?

Comment: you mean base path?

Comment: base path <base href="/">

Comment: does your index.html have <router-outlet></router-outlet>?

Comment: I mean in the definition of `routes`. what is the path in browser after you refresh?

Comment: When i refresh page on base path its work, But navigate to other page and then refresh its not work.

Comment: i am navigate to /signup and then refreshing page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually what I do is include all my api endpoints first, and then at the end add this

```
app.get('*',(req,res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'dist/MEAN-blog/index.html'));
});
```

This way any endpoint that isn't `/api` will return index.html and angular routing will take over from there.

Another alternative is using SSR but its kind of a pain.

Comment: Its working, But may be its not user friendly. Because i am on signup page and refresh page its throw on index page .

Comment: Thanks @Isaac, But there are any other ways ?

Comment: So looking back at your path `dist/MEAN-blog/index.html` you seem to have multiple index.html files.... you should only have 1. Every time a request is made, the response should be index.html, and then you should have routes defined in your angular app that understand what components to render.

Comment: Awesome, if everything is working for you care to accept my answer?

Comment: Also just throwing this out there.. your endpoints like `/register` you should probably prefix with `/api` so it would look like `/api/register`... that way in your angular app you can have a route defined `/register` that will render your register component and there arent any conflicts between your client routing and back end routing. Its general best practice.

Comment: Okay Brother, I understood now.